# Is running YUI compressor very load intensive?

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

Why is it eating up all my CPU like crazy?

load average: 4.60, 4.26, 2.55

Comment: What are those units? %? I don't see a question here.

Comment: @matt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29

Comment: try running `top` to see what's using the CPU

Comment: YUI Compressor is making my load go go 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be, depending on the engine and compression ratio. The better the end results, the more resources you should expect to have to spend.

Answer (score 1):

Load going to 9.0 from a single process (YUICompressor, anything else) doesn't make a lot of sense. How are you *running* it?  What else is going on concurrently?

The "load average" is a metric that tells you how many processes are waiting for the CPU over some window of time. If you're doing nothing other than running YUICompressor (or any other **single** program) the load average won't get much bigger than 1 - that means that the compressor is *mostly* using the CPU, and some other periodic tasks and other running programs (X11, your IDE, a music player, and other random things) are competing for the CPU a little.

To get up to a load average of 9, something else must be going on.